# Какое окончание у сказуемого и какой синтаксической роли "не что иное"?

Tags: грамматика, местоимения

Не что иное, как звезда, засиял.. на горизонте.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: ***Не что иное, как звезда засияла на горизонте.***

А запятую мы уберем, зачем нам здесь запятая? Сравнить: ***Не что иное, а звезда засияла на горизонте.***

Союз КАК в данном сочетании равнозначен  противительному союзу А. "Не что иное, как" —  это устойчивое сочетание: отрицание с противопоставлением,  раздельное написание отрицательной частицы  НЕ.

Обособление было бы нужно в таком предложении: *Звезда, а не что иное, засияла на горизонте.*

Пример: Он вывесил ящик для жалоб и писем перед своим замком, потому что ведь **он, а не кто другой,** был отцом отечества (Ю. Тынянов).